# how to get access token from google using client id through triggering url in extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, firefox-addon, google-oauth

in my extension while authneticating users using facebook its quite simple process

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=id&response_type=token&scope=email&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"></a>
```

if you look at the authentication mechanism using facebook its quite simple it gets the data through that url  and sends the data to particular html where we can grab the acces token and do what ever we want

but the mechanism is different for google

but is there anything similar to this where i can authneticate using google

i have refereed a lot of sites

but its of no use

Comment: For chrome extensions you have [chrome.identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity).

Comment: for mozilla addon ?

Comment: [Browser identity API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity)